# React remove bootstrap.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, router

Hello i have created new react app

there is **index.tsx** in src   and all it contains is

```
 import("./bootstrap")
```

if i remove this import or modify it the app stops working

the **bootstrap.tsx** file contains this

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const Root: React.FC = () => <App />;

render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

how can i remove it ?

i would like to if my index.tsx would containt

something like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById('root')
```

app.tsx

```
interface AppProps {
  appPath?: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Route path="/" exact component={View1Component} />
    </HashRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: can you show your complete `app.tsx`?

Comment: added @burningalc

Comment: And `index.tsx` as well, thanks.

Comment: index tsx is just  -> import("./bootstrap")

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem.

To remove bootstrap simply run the command below in your `terminal` or `cmd`

```
npm uninstall bootstrap
```

This will automatically uninstall bootstrap from your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Just by the nature of this question I assume there's plenty answers on the internet and for sure in S.O. that will answer this.

Also, I invite you to put the error that it appears when you remove that bootstrap import.

However, I will try my best for now, have you tried the obvious, `npm uninstall bootstrap` and the removing the import line from the index file?

Let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

For me this's what worked :

```
npm uninstall react-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I want focus on the problem and not solution. I feel your naming is not follow of front-end community. in front-end community we use two filenames as root file. `index.tsx` or `main.tsx` . `bootstrap` word used in  java community often.

**HINT**: in front-end community, bootstrap point to a library(CSS/JS).

for safe rename . you need to edit `package.json` or `index.html` .